# What is the equivalent of Titan getType in Blueprints?

Tags: graph, graph-databases, titan, tinkerpop

I'd like to switch to using Blueprints as much as possible, so how would I do something like Titan's `getType` in Blueprints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Blueprints, there is no special class for types like `TitanKey`, since this is not required in every graph framework.

In Blueprints, you just specify the key name as `String`. The underlying graph implementation, in your case TitanBlueprintsGraph, then wraps itself.

You can see [here](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/master/blueprints-core/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/Element.java#L31), how to get all keys on a specific blueprints element and [here](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/master/blueprints-core/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/Element.java#L40), how to set them.

[This is](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/master/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanElement.java#L83) where titan encapsules the string and the key, while you can see [here](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/master/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/vertices/AbstractVertex.java#L207) how it is implemented.

Comment: Good answer, @Chasmo. This will be even more true in TinkerPop3.  All index creation functions will have to be performed through the native Graph APIs.  There is too much discrepancy among graph providers to generalize index creation and management.

Comment: That sounds realy good. Im excited to see TinkerPop3 and how it will perform in production.